# Meet a friend at Heathrow airport

Tags: layovers, short-connections, lhr, brazil, madrid

I am travelling from Rio de Janeiro to Madrid, with a three-hour layover at Heathrow Airport.

I would like to meet up with one of my close friends during the layover, but we will not be leaving the airport; we just want to have a coffee together in the terminal. I have a handbag and a small cabin case with me.

Would this interval be enough to meet her?

Comment: Suggest you add the following info to help us answer: 1) is the connection same-terminal or will you need to transfer between terminals? 2) is your friend also catching a flight or will they be landside? 3) do you need a visa to enter/transfer in the UK?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe. Heathrow has a [site](https://www.heathrow.com/connecting-flights) that can tell you their expected connection times. Other than potential terminal changes, you would have to go through security again. From experience, that can take 30 minutes or more. Or 5 minutes, it all depends on a bunch of things outside of your control.